# Will the transpose of a Markov Chain matrix have an eigenvalue of 1?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

P is a markov chain matrix (row rums = 1). Consider Q as the transpose of P, with column sums = 1 instead of row rums = 1. Will Q also have 1 as an eigenvalue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; in general every square matrix has the same eigenvalues as its transpose.  One way to see this is to note that a matrix has the same determinant as its transpose, and then note that $(A-\lambda I)^T = A^T - \lambda I$.